# I need to pick only first 10 character other than that I want to exclude it

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Query I am using is this.

```
select orig, term, dial
from rej
where `company = 'goog' and code = '301' and left(term,3) = '011'`
and dial in (select substring(dial, 0, 11) from rej)

   orig             term                 dial       
4046591010         0112489826790      2489826790 
9546674396         0115743064558      5743064558  
4844410151         0113537124         3537124
8588763590         0113653            4653
```

I need only "dial" only with 10 digits there inconsistent character into this column which I don't need. 
After getting this I need to remove the 011 from term then
so in the end it should look like

```
   orig             term                 dial       
4046591010         2489826790         2489826790 
9546674396         5743064558         5743064558
```

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: It helps keep SO Cleaned up if you can accept an answer, or provide more clarification to help needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select orig, stuff(term, 1, 3, '') as term, dial
from rej
where company = 'goog' and
      code = '301' and
      left(term, 3) = '011' and
      dial in (select substring(dial, 0, 11) from rej) and
      len(dial) = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want only items where the dial column is 10 chars long.

```
select orig, term, dial
from rej
where `company = 'goog' and code = '301' and left(term,3) = '011'`
    and dial in (select substring(dial, 0, 11) from rej)
    and len(dial) = 10
```

Should select only when dial is exactly 10 chars. [Len Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx)